# Complex gradient object with transparent center

Tags: adobe-illustrator

This question is a follow-up to [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/130491/41100).

Does doing it this way mean I can make the centre of the tube transparent? If not, are there any alternative procedures that would allow me to make the center transparent?

Answer (score 1):

Just click the middle slider and choose your desired amount of opacity.

See the image below:

[image]