# Pattern brush options

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, brush, blending-objects

I've been playing around with the different options suggested [in this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/130486/gradients-complex-shape-illustrator).

Does anyone have any insight in the pattern brush option? I've tried using the blend tool for three different boxes and colours as suggested. This is what happens using the 'smooth colour' option (I need to use white as the central colour for some reasons, a transparent box doesn't seem to work?):
[image]

Then I apply the smooth colour option on the blend tool between each box:

[image]

And then expand. When I drag this into the brushes panel and choose 'Pattern Brush' to create, I get this:
[image]

...with no options for corners or edges etc.

Comment: Hello. Can you link the original question?

Comment: Course - https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/130486/gradients-complex-shape-illustrator

Comment: Apologies, I was confused as told not to use comments for follow up questions ha! 
Thank you :)

Comment: How about using the Scott's answer?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to expand the blend before creating the brush... Also I believe Scott's answer in the original question was a better solution (gradient on the stroke)

Comment: oh I also just saw what you wrote at the end of the question :) No need to apologise for anything. Soon you'll have enough reputation to access the [chat] so you can, well, chat with us there :)

Answer (score 1):

Illustrator auto-corner generator is only so smart. Once art reaches some unknown degree of complexity, the corner options are no longer able to extrapolate artwork in an automated fashion. Blends can create very complex brush structures.

However, you are *always* free to create your *own* corner art and then add that to the bush.

Pattern brush corner creation can be an involved, lengthy thing depending upon the artwork. It's not something which is easily detailed in a Q<>A format. If you [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=create%20corner%20art%20for%20Illustrator%20pattern%20brush&oq=create%20corner%20art%20for%20Illustrator%20pattern%20brush&aqs=chrome..69i57j33.6663j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) you can find a number of tutorials.

Here are a few video tutorials...

- https://every-tuesday.com/pattern-brushes-corners/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LHANgr35HzA
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GgnvKb_Mgg